# First name vs. Forename

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

I really don't understand why others are using "forename" instead of "first name". Can someone explain the difference to me?

Comment: A spelling note, we usually spell "forename" with no space but "first name" with a space.

Comment: Here's a forum with some discussion you might find useful. I'm still looking for sources to answer your question. http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic21659.html

Comment: You can also use the word "surname" to mean "last name".

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever even heard "forename", here in the US -- just "first name".  But in other cultures it's common to have more than the usual first/middle/last of the US, and it's not unusual for the surname (family name) to be other than the last name, so likely there is a need for additional terminology.

Comment: Pardon with my grammar. I'm not really good in English ... @sumelic thanks..

Comment: No problem, this is a place to learn. You don't need to have great English; all we expect is that you communicate effectively, and that you'll try your best to get the rest right. I edited your question in this case, but you can also do it yourself if you ever want to.

Comment: Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may be of interest, as this site is oriented to advanced speakers and to language scholars.

Comment: I think the fact that some Asian cultures list the family name first has prompted some to abandon the western assumption that a person's given name is said first when pronouncing their full name. 'Forename' still means 'first name,' if slightly more concisely, since 'fore' means front. 'Family name' and 'given name' are really the only terms we have that don't specify what order they belong in and they aren't as elegant as one might wish.

Comment: @Elijah some European cultures also list the family name first (Hungary, notably, but also, in official contexts, former Yugoslavia -- possibly a lingering influence of the Austro-Hungarian empire).

Comment: "Forename" sounds like a Germanism. Never heard it in the US.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no generally understood difference in meaning between "forename" and "first name."

They are different because "first name" is the most commonly used term, and "forename" is quite rare. In fact, I don't know if I've ever heard anybody use the term "forename," although it's easy enough to understand what is meant by it. The [Google Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=first+name%2C+forename%2C+Christian+name&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfirst%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cforename%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CChristian%20name%3B%2Cc0) indicates that "first name" has been much more common than "forename" as far back as it goes.

Another synonym is "[Christian name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_name)," which in practice means exactly the same thing as "first name", although the terminology stems from the practice of "christening" or giving someone a name when they were baptized.

However...

*If we really want to stretch to find a difference in meaning between the two*, apparently the plural term "forenames" is sometimes used to refer to the first name and middle name collectively. This is discussed in FumbleFinger's [answer to this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120748/second-name-or-surname-in-british-english/120760#120760), and the usage is also seen in the example sentence for the [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/forename?q=forename)' online definition of "forename":

> *Please check that your surname and **forenames** have been correctly entered.*

(Bolding not in the original.)

But there's rarely a need to talk about this concept, and if I had to, I would find "first names" acceptable terminology as well. I haven't found any examples of the middle name being referred to as a "forename" in the singular, and I wouldn't recommend ever doing so.

Comment: Don't use quotes around the terms in Ngram.

Comment: Some cultures also have multiple surnames, such as those that derive from Iberia.