# Why is it wrong to say "My names are"?

Tags: grammar

I know this much: Your first and last names are considered a collective noun. But I don't know why that is.

One site defines collective nouns like this:

> [Collective nouns are names for a collection or a number of people or
>   things. Words like group, herd, and array are collective noun
>   examples.](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/nouns/collective-nouns/)

So, my question is, *shouldn't this mean that a collective noun is one name for many things instead of many names for one thing*? If it does have this sense, then your first and last names isn't a collective noun, is it?

Or is there another explanation for villainizing the introduction "My names are..."?

Comment: Why do you say that your first and last names are considered a collective noun?  Where does that come from?

Comment: I'm not even sure where, but I've always thought your names  as a collection of names refered to you and so we're a collective noun... until I found that the term 'collective noun' meant something else as in the definition quoted before. That's when I got to really asking, what is the reason we say 'name is' and not 'names are.' Can you throw more light?

Comment: A name is a funny thing, in that it can be made up of several names. We don't usually say that our body is made up of several bodies (they're body parts), or that our address is made up of several addresses (they don't really have a name, just ‘road’, ‘number’, ’town’, etc.); but we do say that our name is made up of names. There are other things that work like this, though: a family (often) consists of several individual families; but if you have 37 cousins we still say that you have _a big family_, not that you have _*big families_.

Comment: A person's _name_ is the full collection of words used to address them.  It is treated exactly like a book's _title_, it can be composed of multiple words, but is treated as a single entity.  For example: The title of my favorite book by Kurt Vonnegut **is** _Breakfast of Champions_.

Comment: My names are MonkeyZeus and Cinnamon; day job and Tuesday nights respectively ;-)

Comment: My names are Bruce Wayne and Batman.

Comment: If it makes things easier, you might think of the question *"What is your name?"* as either `"What is your full name?"` or `"What is your first name?"`, depending on the context of the question. If the (implied) word is included, it's more clear that the plural form '***names***' doesn't fit, or else you would wind up with something like *"What are your (first) names?"* which doesn't make sense because only one of them can be the first one.

Comment: @SeldomNeedy - Although, one could say _What are your forenames?_. See [First name vs. Forename](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257213/first-name-vs-forename)

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with saying "My names are xxx" from the standpoint of English syntax and semantics.  What's "wrong" is simply that the *convention* is to say "My name is xxx", treating your name, regardless of the number of parts, as a single conceptual entity.  One way to view it is that, in "John M Smith", "John" and "M" are (conceptually) adjectives on the noun "Smith".

Comment: The accepted answer in the "first name vs Forename" thread is very Western-culture-centric. The reason for using the terminology of "first" and "last" names is because other cultures don't follow the same conventions. There is no ambiguity about asking "what is the first (or last) word of your name," independent of the different *significance* that the first or last words may have in different cultures. Compare the conventional naming system used in the USA or Britain with those used in Iceland or China, for example.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't think you can really say "John" and "M" are adjectives.  If anything,  "Smith" modifies "John" in much the same way "M" does, as a way to distinguish one John from another. But that doesn't really make any of these words adjectives. All the components in John's name (including whatever "M" stands for) are nouns, and together they are a single noun that happens to occupy multiple words (like "flight attendant" or "letter carrier").  Just as these people don't say "my occupations are..." , neither should John construe his multi-word name as plural.

Comment: @MontyHarder - I said "(conceptually) adjectives", meaning they modify "Smith" in a fashion similar to an adjective.

Comment: @MontyHarder - And why wouldn't you say "My occupations are ..." if you're a writer, a carpenter, and a blacksmith?

Comment: @HotLicks As I said "conceptually" it's more accurate to say "Smith" modifies "John" than vice versa.

 I said "these people" which is to say "flight attendant" and "letter carrier". A letter carrier doesn't say his occupations *are* "letter" and "carrier".  They aren't two separate things; they're one thing.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> I know so much: Your first and last names are considered a collective
>   noun. But I don't know why that is.

First and last names together do not make a collective noun; they make a compound noun.

A noun is the name of a person, place, or thing. When a name, whether it is a person, building, or organization, or something else, points to a particular person, building, etc., it is called a *proper noun*. Some proper nouns are only one word: Mike, Albert, Snickers, Pepsi, etc. Sometimes two word or more words can be joined together to form a **compound noun**. There are rules for how they are joined together, which is another topic, but here are several compound nouns (remember they act together to make ONE noun): prizefighter, beach ball, newsstand, news room, sister-in-law.

When a compound noun is a proper noun, it too is still considered one noun, even if it spans multiple words.

John Smith

*John* **is** in his office.

Mr. *Smith* **is** not in his office today.

*John Smith* **is** back in his office.

*Mexico City* **is** in Mexico. The *Metropolitan Opera House* **is** in New York. We have terrible news; the *George Washington Elementary School* **has lost** its credentials and will be closed down by the city.

Sometimes a person will go by an 'alias' which is like a fake name, a substitute name, used instead of the person's real name.

:  otherwise known as  --Webster's. **alias**. *adv.*

So, here you can use "are." My names are Wilbert Brown, Martin Thomas, and Andrew Welch. My real name is Wilbert Brown. Martin Thomas is my "pen" name I use in writing fiction novels, and Andrew Welch is a business name I use occasionally.

This is a real good explanation of how 'collective' nouns can be singular or plural:

http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/collectivenoun.htm

Compound noun:

https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-1/nouns/lesson-6/compound-nouns

Comment: That must be it--a compound noun! Thanks, Arch.

Comment: Whether it is a proper noun or not, a compound noun often is not just one word.  In many cases it is *singular*, however, which is an entirely different thing.  A compound noun as a subject takes the singular form of its verb if ***the thing it designates*** is singular, as in your examples.  Compare, however, the "St. Louis Cardinals" -- a compound, proper, *plural* noun.

Answer (score 9):

There is no convention for saying *My names are John Smith*.

Why that is, I have no idea - the reasons are lost in the mists of time.But it would be quite non-idiomatic.

However, if you have both a name and a *nom de plume*, you could say *My names are Eric Blair and George Orwell*.

If someone tells you they are *John Smith*, and you need any further middle names they may have, you could say any one of the following:

*Is that your full name?*
*Do you have a middle name?*
*Do you have any other Christian names*.

Comment: Regarding, "My names are John Smith." Wouldn't that more likely become "My names are John and Smith." which would potentially be grammatical and likely understood if... stilted.

Comment: @Vality Said in that way, yes it is idiomatic. But it is an unusual thing to say, unless you are explaining the Western naming convention to an unlikely person who was not familiar with such things!

Comment: You could also say things like "My names all have seven letters" or "My names all begin with A".

Comment: @Vicky Yes. Whether a person's full name is referred to in the singular or the plural is a matter of context. But the usual context calls for singularity.

Comment: *I don't know* doesn't mean *nobody knows*.

Answer (score 1):

For the vast majority, a  **full name** consists of two or more parts. A person's identity is not limited to their *first name* ( the secular version of *christian name*), when filling out official forms we also include any **middle names** we might have, and then our **last name** (also called *surname* or *family name*)

When someone asks: "What is your name?" they are usually referring to our first name, e.g. *John*; otherwise, they will ask: "What's your full name?"

The conventional reply is: "**It's** John Malcolm Smith". Sometimes, people have a **double surname**, also called a *double-barreled name*,a combination of their mother and father's last names: e.g. John Malcolm Fitzgerald-Smith.

I found a Wikipedia article which sums up nicely the situation.

> A **[personal name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_name)** or *full name* refers to the set of names by which an individual is known and that can be recited as a word-group, **with the understanding that, taken together, they all relate to that one individual**. (...)
>   In Western culture, nearly all individuals possess at least one *given name* (also known as a *personal name*, *first name*, *forename*, or *Christian name*), together with *a surname* (also known as a *family name*, *last name*, or *gentile name*)—respectively, the Thomas and Jefferson in Thomas Jefferson—the latter to indicate that the individual belongs to a family, a tribe, or a clan. Inserted between these are one or more "middle names" (e.g., Frank Lloyd Wright, Charles John Huffam Dickens, Anne Elizabeth Alice Louise Mountbatten-Windsor), further establishing such family and broader relationships.

If I said "**My names are** John Malcolm Thomas Fitzgerald Smith" it would sound as if I had two or more identities, or  aliases.