# Classical verbiage for "Middle Name"? "Given" -> "First", "Surname" -> "Last/Family"

Tags: names

| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mattias | John-Mark | Fischer |

1. Given Name *aka. First Name*
2. ?? *aka. Middle Name*
3. Surname *aka. Family / Last Name*

This is what I understand to be the concept of 'Given Name'. But if I'm correct, then what is the formal label for a "Middle Name"?
Under this classical verbiage, does "Middle Name" just fall into a component of the "Given Name"?
Does "Given Name" actually encompass #1 & #2 above?

**Closest [*Similar question*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120748/second-name-or-surname-in-british-english)** I could find, an answer refers to this as "second forename", but then also denies having one.
I cannot think of a person I've met (I live in US) who didn't have a middle name, though I've met many folks with more than 1 "Middle Name".
But that begs the question of where middle-name culture came from.
Is it so uncommon in The <s>Queen's</s> King's English that there is **no** formal / classical version of "Middle Name"?

Edit:
[*That question*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120748/second-name-or-surname-in-british-english) for which this was closed as a duplicate, I linked to **in my original question**,
implying I read it and found it not to answer my question, as explained in the hitherto paragraph.
It does not actually discuss 'middle names' or alternate forms. Therefore it does not answer this question in any way, ergo this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Second name or Surname in British English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120748/second-name-or-surname-in-british-english) The venerable FF includes 'many people have two or more of what I've never heard called anything other than middle names'.

Comment: What's the [old-english] tag doing here? None of the terms you're identifying as "classical" are from Old English; "given name" itself is from the 1800s which is certainly not what "classical" means to me (especially not when "first name" is many centuries older).

Comment: "I cannot think of a person I've met (I live in US) who didn't have a middle name". Really? As well as the non-famous, lots of well-known people don't have middle names including such celebrities and historical figures as Theodore Roosevelt, Abraham Lincoln, Douglas MacArthur, Joanne (JK) Rowling, John Major (ex UK PM), Harry S Truman, David Selznick, Liam and Chris Hemsworth...

Comment: In traditional usage (British, at any rate) a person had one or more 'Christian names' (the name(s) they were baptised with).  With the decline in automatic church membership and the arrival of people of other faiths, the term 'given name' is preferred (names you were given rather than the family name you inherited). A middle name is just a second given name.

Comment: @Laurel because as an American I know that if I don't say "Classical" and "The King's English" (yes both) I'm going to get a million geographic dialects of slang. Y'all know what I'm talkin' 'bout

Comment: The OP has offered reasons for not regarding this question as a duplicate, and it is not clear why these reasons were ignored by those who voted to close the question. While it is true that the answers to the other question **incidentally** touch upon the subject matter of this one, the questions have different focus.

Comment: Is *verbiage* the word you really want here?

Comment: I don't understand what "hitherto paragraph" is intended to mean.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn’t describe *given name* as “more formal than” *first name*, nor *surname* as more formal than *last* or *family name*. If there’s a parallel distinction, it may be simply that *given name* and *surname* are less colloquial (in American English, anyway) than are *first*, *family*, and *last name*.

On this reading, the state of affairs you ask about amounts to “Two of the three typical components in English-Language names have multiple labels. Does the third one have other labels as well?”

Technically, many of the names we call middle names are also given names: those that, like our first names, are selected by one’s parents and bestowed (given) at birth. By contrast, surnames are typically treated as inherited automatically and without choice.

Comment: "what we call a middle name certainly is also a given name". This isn't true for all middle names. In the Christian (Catholic?) tradition, there's a ["confirmation name"](https://www.catholic.com/qa/what-happened-to-confirmation-names) that's chosen by children around the age of 12 based off the name of a saint the individual finds admirable. These are used as the only middle name or a second one (at least by some people), though they don't usually have any legal standing.

Comment: You raise a good point, @Laurel. But it’s my understanding that Catholics don’t sense that the confirmation names that they take are even roughly similar to their middle name(s). Perhaps that attitude varies from one confirmee to the next? And does anyone use their confirmation names on (civil) legal documents like voter registrations or passports for precisely specifying their identity? I don’t know. Maybe that’s what you meant by “legal standing”?

Comment: I think that the trend of using a confirmation name in any capacity past confirmation has mostly disappeared but it used to be more popular; some chose to legally change their name based on it. But that's not the only example. Some women legally go by "First Maiden Married" (and "Mrs. Married"), so that's a family name used as a middle name. Again, some people weren't given a middle name at birth.

Comment: A further excellent point, @Laurel. Even my own wife jettisoned her **given** middle name—of which she had never been fond—upon our marrying. She has adopted the first-maiden-married form. Anyway, I’ll edit my answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: This is the closest thing to an actual answer on this page. '"there's a "confirmation name" that's chosen"'
@laurel. Then \@PaulTanenbaum makes an excellent counterpoint that "Christian" names are more similar to "Nick-names" or as put in scripture "New Names" which quickly become their primary call among their community, while often not being reflected in any way on forms, documents or other means which may be considered "Government Name"

but in general "No" would be equally valid.

Comment: A significant difference between "given name/surname" and "first name/last name" is that the latter is culture-specific. In China the surname is first rather than last. Is there an analogous culture-agnostic term for middle name?

Answer (score 0):

In the [OED's Historical Thesaurus](https://www.oed.com/thesaurus/?classId=151984), there are categories for all different types of names. Under "middle name" there is but one entry: "middle name". I even checked the other categories and didn't find anything particularly relevant; it does list "confirmation name" and "maiden name" which are used as middle names sometimes but are obviously not synonymous.

Old English speakers (that is, those before 1086AD) did not even have last names. It wasn't until the [17th century that middle names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_name) began to be used by English speakers. This timing probably accounts for the lack of terms. There are terms for the second of three names in other cultures (such as the Roman *nomen*), but these are not middle names as we know them today.

A note: the alternative terms you identified are not more formal (or more "classical") than first/last name. They're simply easier for a global audience to understand, since in other countries (such as Japan) the family name comes first, followed by the given name.